# Bash: How to get the n-th line of a file within a for-loop without the usage of sed or awk

Tags: bash, shell, unix

In bash, is there a way to dynamically get the n-th line of a file within a for-loop as the loop iterates using head and/or tail commands?

Given a fruits.txt file that contains the following lines:

```
apple
orange
watermelon
peach
```

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
for (( i=0; i<someValue; i++ ))
do
  value="$(head -i fruits.txt)"
  echo $value
done
```

Where the program prints the file line-by-line

Comment: Why you want to go for a long approach when tools for printing the lines without a loop are available? Kindly do elaborate more on this in your post.

Comment: I'm trying to use the values for other calculation other than printing.
i.e. get n-th line of one file, and get n-th line of another file and concatenate. But the iterations through the lines are not sequential, and thus dynamic. (i.e. 12451th line from one file, 124th line from another file)

Comment: If you could post samples in your post with your real scenario we may understand it better and could try to help you in `awk`, `sed` or `perl` itself, kindly do add proper samples with more details.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: Also, how big are the files? It might be easier to read them both into arrays, then access the arrays by index.

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't make much sense, as it excludes `sed` and `awk` which would be the obvious answers, and also restricts the solution to a for loop, whereas a while loop is the more usual choise.

But to answer it literally, you can do something like this:

```
cat fruits.txt 
apple
orange
watermelon
peach

$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
someValue=3
for (( i=1; i<=someValue; i++ ))
do
  value=$(head -n "$i" fruits.txt | tail -n 1)
  echo "$value"
done

$ ./script.sh 
apple
orange
watermelon
```

Comment: Might be an embedded system with `sed` and `awk` disabled?

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ: Sure, everything is possible, but seems a bit strange as these tools are required by POSIX.